# SSH no Linux Utilizando ubuntu

Tags: linux

Qual comando utilizo para o SSH autentificação Também por usuário e senha 
para acessar o servidor sem ter a necessidade de esta fazendo senha criptografada
""

Eu montei um servidor na Amazon sendo que para eu acessar preciso da chave autenticada ate ai entro tranquilo sendo que que criei um outro usuário e quero dar acesso ale sem a necessidade de chave so com login e senha que eu criei dele ( me foi informado que eu preciso habilitar dentro do servidor do ssh autentificação por usuário e senha )me disseram que e só uma linha de comendo mais não estou achando em lugar nenhum  ""

Comment: Não entendi direito

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de mais eu sugeria que não utilizasses autenticação por utilizador/password por questões de segurança. A autenticação por chave deveria ser o método preferencial.

Agora, respondendo à tua pergunta, podes utilizar um bloco `Match` e a directiva `PasswordAuthentication` no ficheiro `sshd_config` (normalmente em /etc/ssh/sshd_config) para seleccionar utilizadores para os quais desejas permitir autenticação através de nome de utilizador/password. Para isso, adiciona no **final do ficheiro** o seguinte:

```
PasswordAuthentication no

Match User fbasilio
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Isto irá desabilitar a autenticação por nome de utilizador/password para todos os utilizadores com excepção de **fbasilio**.

Depois apenas tens que reiniciar o serviço (por exemplo, `/etc/init.d/sshd reload` ou no ubuntu `service ssh restart`)

A razão pela qual deves adicionar isto no final do ficheiro deve-se ao facto de, caso todos os critérios no bloco Match serem verificados, então isto irá afectar todas as linhas até ao próximo bloco Match ou final do ficheiro.

Mais informação em http://linux.die.net/man/5/sshd_config

Comment: Funcionou Valeu brigadão

Answer (score 1):

Normalmente copio a chave RSA pública do meu computador local para as chaves autorizadas do meu servidor remoto, dessa forma basta digitar `ssh user@ip` para se conectar diretamente.

Para fazer isso execute o comando abaixo:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@ip "mkdir -p ~/.ssh && cat >>  ~/.ssh/authorized_keys"
```

> Substitua `user@ip` pelos valores corretos.

Agora execute o comando abaixo para fazer login:

```
ssh user@ip
```

Simples assim :D.

Comment: Um detalhe, se em ambos os computadores o username for o mesmo, por exemplo `bruno`, não é necessário informar o usuário, ex.: `ssh ip` ou `ssh domain.com`.

Comment: Valeu Brigadão tudo ok

Comment: Minha resposta lhe ajudou? Se sim, a marque como a resposta certa.